# Perl: Tee both merged STDOUT + STDERR and STDERR to separate files without CPAN modules

Tags: perl, logging, stdout, stderr, tee

I have searched the internet for different solutions and the closest I have done is an exercise in `open` statements:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;

# Save previous state
my ($old_out, $old_err);

open($old_out, ">&", \*STDOUT) or 
    croak("Cannot save STDOUT: $!\n");
open($old_err, ">&", \*STDERR) or 
    croak("Cannot save STDERR: $!\n");

my ($fh_OUTLOG);
# Make a filehandle for the tee output
open($fh_OUTLOG, "|-", "tee out_err.log") or
    croak("Cannot open filehandle to tee to log file: $!\n");

# Duplicate STDOUT and STDERR to the filehandle
open(STDOUT, ">&", $fh_OUTLOG) or
    croak("Cannot duplicate STDOUT to filehandle: $!\n");

open(STDERR, ">&", $fh_OUTLOG) or
    croak("Cannot duplicate STDERR to filehandle: $!\n");

# Code...


# Restore STDOUT 
open(STDOUT, ">&", $old_out) or
    croak("Cannot restore STDOUT: $!\n");

# Close the filehandle            
close $fh_OUTLOG        
    or croak( ($!) ? "Error closing fh_OUTLOG: $!"
                  : "Exit status $? from tee log.out");

# Restore STDERR   
open(STDERR, ">&", $old_err) or
     croak("Cannot restore STDERR: $!\n");
```

But this code will not produce an log file with STDERR, and I dont know how to add it. The criteria for the solution are:

1. Perl v 5.8.3.
2. No CPAN modules.
3. No Bash extra command to start the script.

I was thinking of using some `tee`solutions for STDERR as well:

```
open(STDERR, "| tee log.err");
open(STDERR, ">&", $fh_OUTLOG);
```

But using this will hang the script in the end of the execution. (Think the tee child process still is alive). But the script still hangs if I try to kill it in the end.

```
my $pid_std_err = open(STDERR, "| tee log.err") or
     croak("Cannot tee filehandle STDERR to log.err: $!\n");

# Code... 

kill -9, $pid_std_err;
```

Comment: Why are you banning CPAN modules? It's like you don't actually want to write Perl code after all. Perl is all about taking the right pre-built pieces and just glueing them together. If you wanted to write it yourself from scratch, go write it in C or something

Comment: Wish I could install CPAN modules but in this project it is not possible.

Comment: How is it you can install code from SO but not from CPAN? What happens if I copy something from CPAN to SO?

Comment: If you can put Perl code in a file on the server and run it, you can install Perl modules. They can be installed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two pipes and associate them wih STDOUT and STDERR.
2. Create a task (thread, process, etc) that uses IO::Select to read from those two pipes.
3. The task places what it reads from those pipes in the appropriate files(s).